# Multiple nested components

Tags: reactjs

I want to make a wrapper on my content so that I can use some general events in there. So it would look like this:

```
var Table = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return (
            React.createElement('div', {},
                React.createElement('div', {className: 'TableDiv'}, 'Table div - click me')
            )
        );
    }

});

var NestedData = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return React.createElement('div', {},
            React.createElement('div', {className: 'NestedDiv'}, 'Nested data div - click me')
        )
    }

});

var App = React.createClass({

    render: function () {
        return React.createElement(Table, {},
            React.createElement(NestedData)
        )
    }

});

window.onload = function () {
    ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(App), document.getElementById('content'));
};
```

The problem is that the nested div is not being displayed, only the Table class wraper. How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis while returning from render function

```
var NestedData = React.createClass({

render: function () {
    return ( 
        React.createElement('div', {},
        React.createElement('div', {className: 'NestedDiv'}, 'Nested data div - click me')
    )
  );
}

});
```